# add single record on top of sql query

Tags: sql

I need to add a single record on top of an sql query eg if there is a table called **proptype** and has 3 records **(ID (int) + Name (nvarchar) = 1 Apartment, 2 Townhouse, 3 Villa)** then I would like to select and sort (on name) those 3 records and add manually a new record **(NULL Please Select)** on top.

The result therefore should be

```
ID     Name

NULL   Select
1      Apartment
2      Townhouse
3      Villa
```

Please advice, thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ID, Name
from 
(
  select null as ID, 'Select' as Name
  union all
  select ID, Name
  from prototype
) as T  
order by case when ID is null then 0 else 1 end, Name
```

Comment: +1 First sort by id (0 or 1) to make sure "Select" is the first row, then by name

Comment: Many thanks, working fine. Also thanks to all others, but this one is the only one which sorts OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(SELECT NULL ID, 'Select' Name)    
UNION
(SELECT * FROM proptype)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NULL as ID, "Please select" AS Name
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name FROM prototype
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT NULL ID, 'Select' Name
UNION
SELECT ID, Name FROM proptype
```